# Can't delete file in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script to refresh my memory as well as advance my learning. The script is supposed to take input and then delete the file the user entered. However `rm` is not working. I've tried `rm -r`, `rm -rf` to no avail. However `rm` works fine outside of the script. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This program will delete data

read -p "Please enter a filename:" $filename

if [[ -e $filename ]]; then    
  echo "Deleting $filename ... one moment"
  rm $filename
  echo "Done"
else 
  echo "Ooops, something went wrong.: Try again?, [y,n]?"
fi
```

Comment: Does the filename have spaces in it?

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Always quote your variables: `rm "$filename"`, many errors happen because of forgetting to do this.

Comment: @Barmar, no error message it just skips to the else statement

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with `rm`, the problem is with the `if`.

Comment: That means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see each command as it's executed, with the variables expanded.

Comment: You have a typo: you shouldn't have `$` before `filename` in the `read -p` line.

Comment: @Barmar: That was my thought, too.

Comment: @W0z, Are you try to delete a directory?

Comment: @MilanKarunarathne no just a text file in Documents. Basically I want the file to prompt the user for a file to delete, all of these are basic text files or other types of files such as .py, I actually made another script and included the text file name next to rm , ran it and the script was deleted. I'm not sure if something is wrong with my if statement, although it doesn't appear so to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is running on the right permissions so it can actually delete the file and also try using the **absolute path** of the file without whitespaces to make sure the input is ok

Answer (score 0):

Running `rm` without complete path to delete a file is always dangerous. So try adding ABSOLUTE path to your file names and then pass it to `rm` command else you may see consequences in case file is not found.

***EDIT:*** You could change your script to as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This program will delete data
echo "Please provide file name with complete path which you want to delete: eg--> /tmp/test_file"
read -p "Please enter a filename:" filename
if [[ -e "$filename" ]]; then 
 echo "Deleting $filename ... one moment"
 rm "$filename"
 echo "Done"
else 
    echo "Ooops, something went wrong.: Try again?, [y,n]?"
fi
```

Also you could add `&& "$filename" =~ /\//` condition too in your `if` condition in case you want to make sure a Absolute path has been provided by user or not.